# Browser Authentication Not Reset

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer-8

We have an application which routes a user to different modules based on the htaccess login.  A client using IE8/Windows 7 claims that closing his browser did NOT reset his htaccess authentication and he was not able to switch modules.  I cannot replicate it, and the frustrated client is unwilling to provide any more feedback.  Does anyone know of a setting in IE8 that might make the authentication persist upon re-launch?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IE8 asked to save the password and he hit yes, the password is persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > User Accounts > Advanced tab > Manage Passwords

Anything listed there will be persistant